# MyBatis-guice with AWS Lambda and IAM auth fails with PAM authentication error

Tags: java, postgresql, aws-lambda, mybatis, pam

I am trying to connect to RDS Aurora Postgres instance using IAM auth and MyBatis-Guice to run some insert statements. The setup works fine initially. However, after sometime, lambda invocation fails with `FATAL: PAM authentication failed for user "xxx"`. This usually occurs when there are concurrent invocations. But then, the next invocations succeed.

This is my DAO method:

```java
@Transactional(executorType=ExecutorType.BATCH, isolationType=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void insertEntities(List<Entity> entities) {
    for(Entity entity: entities) {
        myMapper.insert(entity);
    }
}
```

This error should not occur because IAM token and Lambda both have a time limit of 15 minutes.
Also, looking at the source code, I see that the dataSourceProvider is bound to the DataSource in Singleton scope in MyBatisModule. My guess is that some concurrent lambda `getAuthToken()` call changes the expected token for the postgres role and when any other 'warm' concurrent lambda gets invoked (along side the lambda which changed the password) and opens a new managed session with the DataSource configured with the older token, it receives the `PAM authentication` error.

How could I mitigate this?

Answer (score 0):

I set the password each time the Lambda function was invoked. I made a few changes to my DAO method and used SqlSession instead of Mappers. This is to avoid the caching of SqlSession the underlying SqlSessionManager does when using Mapper methods directly in mybatis-guice with `@Transactional`. The SqlSessionFactory used here is in Singleton scope and is injected into the DAO instance.

```java
public void insertEntities(List<Entity> entites) {
  try(SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession(ExecutorType.BATCH, TransactionIsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED) {
    try {
      MyMapper myMapper = session.getMapper(MyMapper.class);
      // do something
      session.commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      session.rollback();
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

And on each invocation, I set the password as the IAM auth token in the datasource.

```
MyDataSource dataSource = (MyDataSource) sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().getEnvironment().getDataSource();
dataSource.setPassword(generator.getAuthToken(request));
```

Now whenever the Lambda function is invoked, the DataSource will have a new auth token and will be able to connect to the database.